# How to make trigger code execute only for a specific application?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I was wondering if it is possible to enable a trigger just for my current application and not for any sql executed against the table.

The situation:

There are two applications working on the same database. App1 and App2.

I have a trigger on 'MyTable' which should only be fired when App1 is executing a query, but not when App2 is doing so.

Comment: Well its logical . isn't it ?
where would you have the app name ?
If you do have access to it in the trigger ( inserted ) then its easy .

Comment: Patric, as an alternative to using `APP_NAME()`, you can also use [`SET CONTEXT_INFO`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17525/2660).  `SET CONTEXT_INFO` is commonly used to send info to triggers like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While not a good design, it is doable. You'll need to put logic in the trigger so it causes the code to only be executed when the correct application is connected.

```
Create trigger... 
As
    If app_name() = 'something' 
    begin 
        put code here 
    end
```

Comment: It may not be a concern in this specific case, but other potential readers should note that `app_name()` is very easy to spoof via connection string properties.

Comment: Yup, very easy to spoof. Don't do this for security purposes, but for working around minor software deficiencies, or other convenient tricks, you're probably okay. We've got a few that do this.

Comment: Very true, this would be VERY easy to get around. But assuming that there's no naught intentions of the application users (I can't believe I just put that) it'll work.  Not the best idea, but it'll do the job.  Jon, thanks for formatting. Wasn't going to try doing that on my phone.